Downloaded images and thumbnails much larger than specified area of interest using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API
I am a novice with Google Earth Engine.
The aim of my code is to enable Sentinel-2 images (along with an NDVI layer) to be downloaded for a specified time period for a specified area of interest (aoi). The aoi I use are generally quite small - the current one is just 6 acres. I have uploaded a shape file as an asset to google earth engine and imported it as a variable to enable this code to be reused for other projects.
The code generally appears to work. For example, the aoi, the first image from the collection, and the corresponding NDVI image all appear at the correct size on the GEE map.
The problem occurs with both the image as a thumbnail and when I download the data. The thumbnail appears to cover an enormous area such that the thumbnail of the aoi area is either barely or not visible, and the downloaded rasters come in four parts - which I understand is because the underlying raster is large.
I have checked the coordinates of both the aoi and the first image from the image collection. They are very different. The aoi coordinates are as I have specified (5 points for a rectangle). The image collection consists of 19 coordinate points spread over several degrees of latitude/longitude.
I assume this is a filtering/cropping issue and have tried as many ways as I can think of to try and fix this with no avail.
Note: if I add the aoi as a rectangle (e.g. using ee.Geometry.Rectangle), the above problem does not occur. Both the thumbnail and raster display as expected.
Can you point out the issue with the code?
Code below (some of my test code is still included and commented out):
//Script: General
var aoi = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-cameronleckie/assets/240503-PCW-AOI');
// Add shapefile as an asset. Import into script and rename var to aoi from table

Map.addLayer(aoi,{}, 'AOI', true); // Adds the aoi to the map viewer
print('AOI properties',aoi);

// Find centroid of AOI - Apply the centroid method to the Polygon object.
var aoiCentroid =  aoi.geometry().centroid();

// Extract centroid coordinates
var centroidCoordinates = aoiCentroid.coordinates();
var longitude = centroidCoordinates.get(0);
var latitude = centroidCoordinates.get(-1);
print('Longitude: ', longitude);
print('Latitude: ', latitude);

// Construct a point from coordinates (used for filtering) and print to map viewer
//var point = ee.Geometry.Point(lat, long);
var point = ee.Geometry.Point(longitude.getInfo(),latitude.getInfo());
Map.addLayer(point,{}, 'Centre', true);

// Center the map
Map.setCenter(longitude.getInfo(), latitude.getInfo(), 15); // example of programatically doing this.

// Variable to store sentinel collection, filtered by date, centre point and cloudy percentage
var sentinelCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
.filterDate('2024-03-01', '2024-05-04')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 2)) // ...filters on the metadata for pixels less than x% cloud  
.filterBounds(aoi)  // filter by intersection aoi
.map(function(image){return image.clip(aoi)}); // From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61220828/how-to-clip-an-image-collection-to-a-feature-collections-geometry#61220982

// Get the number of images and print details of collection images to console.
var count = sentinelCollection.size();
print('Count: ', count);
print (sentinelCollection);

var sentinelCollectionList = ee.ImageCollection(sentinelCollection).toList(sentinelCollection.size());
var sentinelCollectionImage = ee.Image(ee.List(sentinelCollectionList).get(0)); //note index 0 is the first image

// Function to clip collection to aoi - didn't appear to work
//var clip = function(image){ 
//    return image.clip(aoi);
//}

// Apply function to collection
//var clc_col = sentinelCollection.map(clip);
//var checkList = ee.ImageCollection(clc_col).toList(clc_col.size());
//var checkImage = ee.Image(ee.List(checkList).get(0)); //note index 0 is the first image
//print('clc_col', checkImage);

// Display first image in list
print('Sentinel Image',sentinelCollectionImage);
Map.addLayer(sentinelCollectionImage,{bands: ['B4', 'B3','B2'], min: [0,0,0], max: [2000,2000,2000]},'Sentinel2',true);

// Display all metadata.
print('All metadata:', sentinelCollectionImage);

// Display thumbnail of first image in list
//Why is the thumbnail so small. Same as for the movie strip where the image is tiny amongst a much bigger background.
// Maybe not clipped properly?
// Checked image coordinates and they are much much bigger than the coordinates of the aoi
// Therefore need to crop image.

// Width and Height of the Thumbail image.
var pixels = 64;
// Set parameters
var parameters = {
  //dimensions: [768,768],
  dimensions: [pixels, pixels],
  //region: aoi,
  crs: 'EPSG:3857',
  format: 'png',
  bands: ['B4', 'B3','B2'], 
  min: [0,0,0], 
  max: [2000,2000,2000]
};

// Create a thumbnail with no background fill.
// Masked pixels will be transparent.
print(ui.Thumbnail({image: sentinelCollectionImage.clip(aoi), params: parameters}));

// Calculate NDVI for single image

//Function to add NDVI image to an existing image
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI'); // Sentinel 2 bands, Red = B4, NIR = B8. Ref: https://gisgeography.com/sentinel-2-bands-combinations/
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

// Test the addNDVI function on a single image & display.
var ndvi = addNDVI(sentinelCollectionImage).select('NDVI');

var ndviParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};

// add NDVI to all images in collection (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_api_06)
var withNDVI = sentinelCollection.map(addNDVI); // Tested - this works
Map.addLayer(withNDVI);
print('With NDVI', withNDVI);

/* Download image collection. References:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868762/exporting-all-images-in-a-google-earth-engine-image-collection-google-earth-eng
- https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/wiki/Batch
*/

var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch'); 
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(withNDVI, "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CzFPAbOhjVfElp8wcztLUdp2TOTT0jjG?usp=share_link", {scale:10});

// Retrieve the projection information from a band of the original image.
// Call getInfo() on the projection to request a client-side object containing
// the crs and transform information needed for the client-side Export function.
var projection = sentinelCollectionImage.select('B2').projection().getInfo();
print('Projection:', projection);
print('Scale in meters:', sentinelCollectionImage.select('B2').projection().nominalScale());

